# How to publish android app to galaxy store my binary i always recieve this binary cannot be registered

Tags: store, publish, galaxy, huawei-developers, amazon-appstore

My Binary file cannot be registered on galaxy store. After i uploaded the apk i get this error(This binary cannot be registered. please try again later).

Answer (score 2):

Apparently after several tries and error elimination in vain as there were not any technical errors concerning the app. The only error was a glitch in my connection. Trying a different connection solved the problem. The process is straight forward as described both on amazon and Samsung portal.